# If i run a Hive query to fetch data from latest partition only, will the query do a Full table scan?

Tags: hive

If my Hive table is partitioned on a column called data_loading_date.If i run a query to fetch data from latest partition only,  will the query do a Full table scan ?
But the key point here to note is that , latest partition will be identified by a query itself(i.e using select max(data_loading_date) from table_A )
Query would be something like:

```
select *  
from table_A 
where data_loading_date in (
   select max(data_loading_date) from table_A
);
```

Comment: You can run `explain select * ...`, and check generated query plan.

Comment: This is where partition work, it will not scan the whole table. It will only access the partition that will be mentioned in the condition